# why is there additional information the first commit line in git log output?

Tags: git

The first commit line in my `git log` has recently started showing:

commit 8d8cc487c2b91a2d18edbfbafe9d6700f764fe04 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)

Head -> (in blue)
master -> (in green)
origin/master and origin/HEAD (in red)

What is this telling me and why did it start showing up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the output of the `--decorate` option of `git-log`. I think that it changed the default value, from `none` to `short` at some recent `git` version.

When that `git log --decorate` (or `git config log.decorate`) is `short`, then for each commit shown in a log it will show also any alternate name that refers to this commit. The color is the type of name:

- Green: local branch.
- Red: remote branch.
- Brown: tag.
- Blue: symbolic name, such as `HEAD`, a name that refers to other name. You will see an arrow `->` pointing to that other name.

If you don't like it (but why shouldn't you?) you can disable it with `git config log.decorate none`.

Comment: That is correct, this was changed in git [2.13.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.13.0.txt),m which reads "The default behaviour of "git log" in an interactive session has been changed to enable "--decorate"."

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Thanks for looking it up. I remembered having configured that option in the past to get those nice looking colors... It is good to see that my personal preferences are becoming the default! 8-P.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful and complete answer. I don't want to get rid of it but I didn't understand what it was showing. I wanted to make sure it didn't indicate that the repository was in a state that was not quite normal.

Answer (score 4):

In order:

- HEAD is the commit that Git is currently pointed at.
- master represents the the tip of your branch.  Here, master could be any other branch.
- origin/master represents the tip of your remote branch.
- origin/HEAD represents the commit that Git is pointed at on your remote repository.